# wrote a launch file foe robocup 14 world. but i can't launch it

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using ros indigo with the gazebo that came with it.

```
<?xml version= "1.0" ?>
<launch>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
    <arg name="world"  default="gazebo_ros_range"/>
    <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
    <arg name="physics"  default="ode"/>

    <group if="$(arg use_sim_time)">
     <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    </group>

    <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)
                                /launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
    

       <arg name="world_name" value="/usr/share/gazebo-2.2/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world"  />
       <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
       <arg name="physics" value="$(arg physics)"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301317/wrote-a-launch-file-foe-robocup-14-world.-but-i-can%27t-launch-it/) by [aregbede60@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37121/aregbede60@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-08-23**:
Can't launch it? What is the error it gives you?

**Comment by [aregbede60@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37121/aregbede60@gmail.com/) on 2018-08-23**:
the error it gives is this
while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo                                 /launch/husky_empty_world.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo                                 /launch/husky_empt

**Comment by [aregbede60@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37121/aregbede60@gmail.com/) on 2018-08-23**:
i wrote
roslaunch /home/victor/Ex1/huskyEx1.launch
in the terminal

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-08-23**:
Looks like there is "no such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo /launch/husky_empty_world.launch" . Ros is looking for your world file there, is it there?. Not sure if the space and the 'u' in the error is some formatting issue or it actually looks like that.

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-08-23**:
In any case the line that is giving you trouble is the one below:
<include file="$(find husky_gazebo)
                                /launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
Make sure the file exists. If you enter $ roscd husky_gazebo in the terminal does it match where it's looking in the error?

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-08-23**:
Start by deleting all the white-space between `file="$(find husky_gazebo)` and `/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a white-space gap in the path for the husky_empty_world.launch file so roslaunch is looking for the wrong file.

```
<include file="$(find husky_gazebo)<------ white space
             -------->/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
```

This should be as below instead:

```
<include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE :**

Well this is progress, the first error is fixed. The error is telling you that the `husky_empty_world.launch` file doesn't use the arguments [debug, physics] so you can't pass them to it, roslaunch is very strict on this. If you remove the lines below, it should solve this error:

```
   <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
   <arg name="physics" value="$(arg physics)"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aregbede60@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37121/aregbede60@gmail.com/) on 2018-08-23**:
tried this. but got this error instead

unused args [debug, physics] for include of [/opt/ros/indigo/share/husky_gazebo/launch/husky_empty_world.launch]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-23**:
okay, see my updated answer.

**Comment by [aregbede60@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37121/aregbede60@gmail.com/) on 2018-08-24**:
so i did what you guys said, ii actually launched. but it launched a husky simulation. i actually wanted to launch a robocup14_spl_field.world. don't know if i need to install it first before am able to launch the robocup 14 spi field

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-24**:
Well you are including a husky_gazebo launch file! I suggest creating a single launch file without anything to do with husky, to load this world for you.